# How do you keep an object horizontal in THREE.js?

Tags: three.js

I have some text in THREE.js that I would like to face the camera *AND* be horizontal regardless of where the camera is positioned.

I can make it face the camera with `(text.lookAt(camera.position)` but when I move the camera around it rotates around the viewing direction axis.

[image]

[image]
Is there a way to get it to remain facing the camera AND at a fixed angle of rotation around the vector `text.position - camera.position`.

Comment: try `text.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion)`

Comment: You are quite right it works @prisoner849 can you explain why and I can accept your answer

Comment: The line explains itself :) You simply copy value of quaternion of the camera to the quaternion of the text object, thus the text always has the same angles as the camera has. Sprite-like technique.

Comment: How is that different from setting text.rotation = camera.rotation ?

Comment: The same way: `text.rotation.copy(camera.rotation)`, but, as the practice shows, better to use quaternions instead of Euler angles. For example, to avoid the gimbal lock.